# NSURLConnection timed out

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I have a web service. When i hit a server it almost take above 1 minute to get the response. When i run the app in simulator getting response null in 50 sec. It won't be waited for few more minutes. My code shows below.

```
- (void)functionCalling
{
     functionName = @"productList";
     baseURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.0.13/dashly-server/mobile/  Magento-IOS/lib.php?functionName=%@",functionName];
     NSLog(@"%@",dateSelect);
     NSString *baseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&store_url=%@&api_username=%@&api_key=%@&fromDate=%@&toDate=%@",store_url, api_username, api_key, fDate, tDate];
     NSString *completeURL3 = [baseURL stringByAppendingString:baseString];
     NSURL *url3 = [NSURL URLWithString:[completeURL3 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     NSLog(@"url is  %@", url3);
     //NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url3];
     NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                     initWithURL:url3
                                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                     timeoutInterval:180.0];

     theConnection3 = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
     NSLog(@"connection = %@",theConnection3);
     if( theConnection3 )
     {
          //webData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[completeURL1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
          webData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:url3];
          theRequest.HTTPBody = webData;
          NSLog(@"web response data %@", webData);
          NSString *response3 = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
          NSLog(@"response products = %@", response3);
     }
     else
     {
          NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
     }

}
#pragma mark
#pragma mark Actions - NSURLConnection Methods

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [self->webData  setLength:0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self->webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@" , error);

}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError *error;
    NSString *resStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:webData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"dash response = %@", resStr);
    if ([resStr isEqualToString:@"null"]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"No Products Today..." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else if ([resStr length]==0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Web services connection failed..." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        id jsonObject3 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSArray *array = (NSArray *)jsonObject3;
        for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
        {
             dict = [array objectAtIndex:i];
             [productIdArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"productId"]];
             [productNameArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"name"]];
             [ordersArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"nooforders"]];
             [priceArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"price"]];

        }
        NSLog(@"product id array %@", productIDArray);
        NSLog(@"name array %@", productNameArray);
        NSLog(@"orders array %@", ordersArray);
        NSLog(@"price array %@", priceArray);
    }    
}
```

After hitting the server at 50 sec time i got the alert "Web services connection failed". Even i am sending time interval 180 sec it won't wait for such long time. How can i solve this issue? I want to wait until response came. Can i use NSOperationQueue here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't a problem to need one minute to display products ?

Comment: but store is slow basically we can't do anything

Comment: It could be the server who terminates the request if it can't render a response in 50 seconds. But I agree with @ffarquet, that's a hell of a long time to wait.

Comment: A priori, the connection shouldn't fail if you increase the timeout that way. Isn't the server that closes the connection ? Can you print the whole error you get ? But personally, I would focus on optimizing the web server before doing an app. I don't think you will get a lot of clients if you have to wait more than a minute to display content... Have you thought about a better server ? Another web platform ? Caching ? Distributed computing ?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as it is `-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` that is called and not `-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`, the connection is surely terminated by the server due to a timeout on the server side.

You are probably receiving a bad HTTP status code. Try to display it. However, you should first consider to improve your service performance instead of making your system work with longer timeouts.

Comment: i didn't get any error. Service must be requested timed out. web response data must be null.